# Finding unused values in message resource file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, resources

I am working on a project that has been through multiple hands with a sometimes rushed development. Over time the message.properties file has become out of sync with the jsps that use it. Now I don't know which properties are used and which aren't. Is there a tool (eclipse plugin perhaps) that can root out dead messages?

Comment: If the keys are not dynamically generated (like concatenating a prefix with a suffix to get the final key), you could just loop through the keys and grep each key in all the JSPs. I'm not a script expert, but this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: start with an empty bundle (or from a base after u identified the obvious ones by grep etc) and keep updating it on a need basis. you can do this in QA or DEV env by running some functional tests...I doesn't see any other better way...

Comment: I would just bind your original `ResourceBundle` into another custom `ResourceBundle` implementation (via `ResourceBundle#setParent()`), with `handleGetObject()` method doing some logging (or collecting the statistics) on each request but always returning `null`. By looking at this statistics you will learn which keys are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that messages may be accessed by JSP or Java, and resource names may be constructed rather than literal strings.

Simple `grep`ping may be able to identify "obvious" resource access. The other solution, a resource lookup mechanism that tracks what's used, is only semi-reliable as well since code paths may determine which resources are used, and unless every path is traveled, you may miss some.

A combination of the two will catch most everything (over time).

Comment: Agh, I completely forgot that validation spits out references to the messages (NotNull.object.field). Methinks I trivialized this problem

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can hide the functionality of `ResourceBundle` behind another façade `ResourceBundle`, which should generally pipe all calls to original one, but add logging and/or statistics collection on the top.

The example can be as following:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class WrapResourceBundle {

    static class LoggingResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
        private Collection<String> usedKeys = new HashSet<String>();

        public LoggingResourceBundle(ResourceBundle parentResourceBundle) {
            setParent(parentResourceBundle);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
            Object value = parent.getObject(key);

            if (value != null) {
                usedKeys.add(key);
                return value;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
            return EMPTY_ENUMERATOR;
        }

        public Collection<String> getUsedKeys() {
            return usedKeys;
        }

        private static EmptyEnumerator EMPTY_ENUMERATOR = new EmptyEnumerator();

        private static class EmptyEnumerator implements Enumeration<String> {

            EmptyEnumerator() {
            }

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return false;
            }

            public String nextElement() {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Empty Enumerator");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggingResourceBundle bundle = new LoggingResourceBundle(ResourceBundle.getBundle("test"));

        bundle.getString("key1");

        System.out.println("Used keys: " + bundle.getUsedKeys());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that some of your keys are run-time generated, I don't think you'll ever be able to find a tool to validate which keys are in use and which ones are not.

Given the problem you posed, I would probably write an AOP aspect which wraps the MessageSource.getMessage() implementation and log all the requested codes that are being retrieved from the resource bundle.  Given that MessageSource is an interface, you would need to know the implementation that you are using, but I suspect that you must know that already.

Given that you would be writing the aspect yourself, you can create a format that is easily correlated against your resource bundle and once you are confident that it contains all the keys required, it becomes a trivial task to compare the two files and eliminate any superfluous lines.

If you really want to be thorough about this, if you already have Spring configured for annotation scan, you could even package up your aspect as its own jar (or .class) and drop it in a production WEB-INF/lib (WEB-INF/classes) folder, restart the webapp and let it run for a while.  The great thing about annotations is that it can all be self contained.  Once you are sure that you have accumulated enough data you just delete the jar (.class) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know that at least two of the major java IDEs can offer this functionality.

- IntelliJ IDEA has a (disabled, by default) Inspection that you can
  use to do this:

  go to Settings -> Inspections -> Properties files ->  ... and enable
  the 'Unused property'

  ..Only problem I had was that it didn't pick up some usages of the property from a custom tag library I had written, which I was using in a few JSPs.
- Eclipse also has something like this ( [http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-202.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-202.htm) ) but I haven't really exhausted the how well it works.